# Golang regexp issue with FindStringSubmatch

Tags: regex, go

I was trying to use regexp to do some pattern matching with the or operator but I got some odd results. I have stripped out everything but the essentials to show the problem with my result.

This is my code:

package main

```
import "fmt"
import "regexp"

func main() {
  authRegexp := regexp.MustCompile("^token=(llll|(.+))$")
  matches := authRegexp.FindStringSubmatch("token=llll")
  fmt.Println("MATCHES", matches, len(matches))
        // MATCHES [token=llll llll ] 3
}
```

Url: http://play.golang.org/p/nLtWQQgveY

The matches array has a length of 3, when I think it should have a length of 2. The last value is an empty string. I dont understand why it does this. Is this a golang bug? How do I submit golang bugs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last empty value corresponds to `(.+)` and just an indication that this capturing group was not 'hit' while matching. In other words, it is completely legitimate. In your case it will be safe to use non-capturing group instead: `(?:.+)` - http://play.golang.org/p/MEkkoGqxho

Comment: I think I have asked the wrong question so I made a new one. But I agree this is a good solution to this question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31682707/golang-regexp-quote-submatch

Answer (score 0):

why no just use:

```
^token=(llll)$
```

[demo](http://play.golang.org/p/w7uV9q059w)