# Golang Regexp Quote submatch

Tags: regex, go

I am trying to extract a submatch value from a regexp but to all for it to disregard a set of quotes if necessary. So far I have this:

url: http://play.golang.org/p/lcKLKmi1El

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "regexp"

func main() {
  authRegexp := regexp.MustCompile("^token=(?:\"(.*)\"|(.*))$")

  matches := authRegexp.FindStringSubmatch("token=llll")
  fmt.Println("MATCHES", matches, len(matches))

  matches = authRegexp.FindStringSubmatch("token=\"llll\"")
  fmt.Println("MATCHES", matches, len(matches))
}
```

`Input`::`Expected Matches`

`token=llll`::`[token=llll llll]`

`token="llll"`::`[token="llll" llll]`

Also note that I want to test for either no quotes, or a single set of quotes. I don't want to be able to have mismatched quotes or anything.

How do I get rid of the empty string that is returned? Is there a better regex to get rid of the quotes?

Comment: Are you parsing attributes? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317053/regular-expression-for-extracting-tag-attributes

Comment: Yes kind of. I want to be able to have a pair or double quotes or no quotes at all. Perhaps this is more complicated?

Comment: Sorry, it is still a bit unclear to me. Do you simply want to get the value without quotes? In this case just get everything after `=` and trim `"`.

Comment: Actually, would be nice to have several use cases like `input-output`.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, I have added an input and expected matches section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, that's it: http://play.golang.org/p/h2w-9-XFAt

Regex: `^token="?([^"]*)"?$`

```
MATCHES [token=llll llll] 2
MATCHES [token="llll" llll] 2
```

Comment: Although this allows for unbalanced quotes.

Comment: Definitely. That's why I'd asked for test cases.

Comment: "I dont want to be able to have mismatched quotes or anything" - I just assumed he didn't want to allow this kind of thing. Just wanted to raise his attention to it in case it produces some unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

`authRegexp := regexp.MustCompile("^token=(.*?|\".*?\")$")`
[Demo here](http://play.golang.org/p/K4_Y5XYgW3).

Comment: The second match is: 
`MATCHES [token="llll" "llll"] 2`

Is it possible not to have the quotes in the match?

Comment: @Gary Unfortunately then, the best other way I can think of doing it is the way you initially said but having an empty group. This is because when `"` are included, capturing group 3 will be empty, but when there are no quotes group 2 will by empty - either way you are left with 1 empty group. It would be easy to get rid of the quotes in my method if the Go regex engine supported lookbehinds or conditionals, but it does not.